# I don't understand template tag with hashtag in vuejs template file

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Please someone explain me how it is work in vue template. I found this code within laravel jetstream and Inertiajs AppLayout.vue file.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That is the shorthand version of a named slot. It is equivalent to `<template v-slot:trigger>`.

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots-Shorthand for documentation on slots and shorthand notation.

Comment: thank you very much for saving my time. yesterday I was trying to figure out what is the actual hack under the hood.